# Resumable approach not returning video id

Tags: vimeo-api

I am making a patch call to upload video using tus approach. My video is getting uploaded to Vimeo but in the response of the patch request, I am not getting video ID.

Is there any way to get the video ID of the uploaded video?

Answer (score 0):

The video id (or in Vimeo API terms, the video uri) is not returned on that tus PATCH request. Instead, look for the uri in the response to your initial POST /me/videos request.

See documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach-step-1